# How can I add multiple instances to a Django reverse foreign key set in a minimal number of hits to the database?

Tags: performance, django-models, foreign-keys, django-related-manager

For example, I have two models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

I have a list of job ids--

```
job_ids = [1, 2, ....]
```

that are pks of Job model instances

I know I can do--

```
for id in job_ids:
    person.jobs.add(job_id)
```

but this will be many more queries than if I could do--

```
person.jobs.add(job_ids)
```

where it would unpack the list and use bulk_create. How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
person.jobs.add(*job_ids)
```

In my case I used a filter query and had a list of objects (as opposed to IDs). I was getting an error similar to

```
TypeError: 'MyModel' instance expected, got [<MyModel: MyModel Object>]
```

...before I included the asterisk.

[credit (another SO question)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4959580/1552045)

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't create your jobs yet, you can create them by adding bulk=False

```
jobs_list=[
     Job(title='job_1'),
     Job(title='job_2')
[

person.jobs.add(*jobs_list, bulk=False) # your related_name should be 'jobs', otherwhise use 'job_sets'.
```