# Django-Rest: Serialising ListField() - '_TaggableManager' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My goal is to add tags to a post. I'm using latest taggit (Requirement: Django-Taggit https://github.com/alex/django-taggit ) and DRF.

**Goal:** To pop `tags` only from posted request. For each tag in the post request to call `post.tags.add("tag1","tag2")` to add these tags to the model.

Currently, my post serialiser is:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.CharField(min_length=0, max_length=30)
    )
    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pub.set_trace()

        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags') # Need to pop tags only
        # to_be_tagged, validated_data = self._pop_tags(validated_data)
        images_data = self.context.get('view').request.FILES
        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        post.tags.add(*tags_data)
        for image_data in images_data.values():
            PostImage.objects.create(post=post, image=image_data)
        return post
```

When I send a post request with the following data:

```
data = { 'title': 'First Post',
         ...
         'tags':'["tag1"]'}
```

I get an error:

> Exception Value: '_TaggableManager' object is not iterable

I also tried sending `'tags':'one, two, three'` and simply `one`

Edit - PDB output:

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
> /Users/gr/Desktop/PycharmProjects/godo/api/serializers.py(112)create()
-> tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags')
(Pdb) tags_data
*** NameError: name 'tags_data' is not defined
(Pdb)
```

**Models.py**

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Post(models.Model):
    objects = LocationManager() # to sort by distance
    tags = TaggableManager()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title)
```

Comment: what is in `tags_data`? just write `tags_data` when pdbed there and copy the output and past it here

Comment: @andilabs It's undefined, I'll make an edit

Comment: could you try using `SlugRelatedField` mentioned by me in your serializer?

Comment: Then I get: FieldError at `/app/posts/`
Cannot resolve keyword 'text' into field. Choices are: `id, name, slug, taggit_taggeditem_items, post`

Comment: Assuming I do `from taggit.models import Tag` which is not the model I created myself (since I'm using the `taggit` library)

Comment: ohhh please paste your models involved here, because it is some misunderstatement here

Comment: @andilabs I've added it

Comment: ok, you should adjust my answer to taggit lib or use approach like mine. I just created model Tag  with simple text=CharField.. and In some other model I use `tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='spot_facilities', null=True, blank=True)`.

Comment: see updated answer with my models.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the content of `tags_data` variable? Could you put there traceback and debug it (see: using `(i)pdb` for debugging)?

I think wrong is these line:
`post.tags.add(tags_data)`
lets try:
`post.tags.add(*tags_data)`

The star unpack list. See these answer for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4959580/953553

In my project I ma handling `tags` which are in model M2M and in serializer I decided to use this approach:

```
tags = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
    many=True,
    queryset=Tag.objects.all(),
    slug_field='text'
)
```

my models:

```
class Spot(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='spot_facilities', null=True, blank=True)


class Tag(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Comment: Hi, the link doesn't work, but I found https://github.com/HassenPy/django-pdb , is that what's needed? I think the problem is that the 'title' is still present in `tags_data`. I'm not sure how to check the content, since I'm using Postman to do post requests, and not python environment itself. (I tried adding * and **)

Comment: I made some changes to the code, and I get the following exception now: Exception Value: '_TaggableManager' object is not iterable

Comment: Thanks, I've added the `pdb` and made an edit. Now it seems the request is stuck, and doesn't give me an error in Postman (says 'loading...' forever)

Comment: hehe this behaviour is ok, you should now go to your console where manage.py runserver is running and you can inspect what happens there.

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet, will try later tonight :)

Comment: I tried it just now, I get: ValueError: Cannot alter field api.Post.tags into api.Post.tags - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields). I'm assuming this is because I simply replaced my `Manager()` with `M2M`. Now my migrations are all messed up.

Comment: I fixed the migrations, but still the same error. `*** NameError: name 'tags_data'` is not defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166700/discussion-between-andilabs-and-grs).