# How to add value to a many-to-many field in Django

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a relation as down below:

```
class Student(AbstractBaseUser):
    # It inherits AbstractBaseUser and has it's own manger
    # note: I did forget to add editable here
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    firstname
    lastname
    ...


class Teacher(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    firstname
    lastname
    email
    ...


class Meeting(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
    teacher = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher)
```

How should I add/set a value to field 'student' or 'teacher'. I tried to assign an object from related models to them but got an **error**:

***Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use student.set() instead.***

And I tried this as well:

```
m = Meeting()
s = Student.objects.first() #to get a random student
m.student.add(s)
```

Then I get:
***ValueError: Cannot add "<Student: sarah@gmail.com>": instance is on database "None", value is on database "default"***

I did this as well:

```
m = Meeting.objects.create() #It does only have two mentioned fields.
m.student.add(s)
```

I get this:
***django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "meeting_id" is of type bigint but expression is of type uuid
LINE 1: ..._meeting" ("meeting_id", "student_id") VALUES ('c7688df9-...
^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add multiple objects to ManyToMany relationship at once in Django ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959499/how-to-add-multiple-objects-to-manytomany-relationship-at-once-in-django) Better yet simply have a look at the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat  I tried this an I got an error. let me update the topic. Thanks

Comment: @TheMir: you should first *create* the `Meeting` at the database side, so `m = Meeting.objects.create()`, or `m.save()`, otherwise it has no pk, and you thus can not link students/teachers to the `Meeting`.

Comment: Does one (or more) of your models use an `uuid` as primary key instead of an `AutoField`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes I commented below your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create a `Meeting` and than populate it with `Teacher`s and `Student`s, so:

```
s1 = Student.objects.create(firstname='Foo', last_name='Bar')
s2 = Student.objects.create(firstname='Qux', last_name='Qux')
t1 = Teacher.objects.create(
    firstname='Some',
    last_name='One',
    email='someone@something.com'
)

m = Meeting.objects.create()
m.student.add(s1, s2)
m.teacher.add(t1)
```

For more information, see the [*Many-to-many relationships* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships).

Based on the exception you shared in the question, you created the `Meeting` model *before* you made primary keys of type `UUIDField`. We can fix this problem by:

1. removing the `Meeting` model;
2. run `makemigrations`;
3. create a new `Meeting` model;
4. run `makemigrations` again; and
5. run `migrate` to update the database.

Comment: Actually I tried this as well. I got an error. Let me add error to the topic.

Comment: @TheMir: as specified in the comments, you need to *create* a database record for the `Meeting` first, so `m = Meeting()` is *not* sufficient, you need to `m.save()`, or simply use `Meeting.objects.create()`.

Comment: I did this. added the error to the topic. I think It has an error related to types in DB. Considering all the models have id with type uuid4.

Comment: @TheMir: It might be better to *share* the details regarding the primary keys of your models.

Comment: My bad. Just a moment.

Comment: I added more details.

Comment: @TheMir: is it possible that you *first* constructed the `Meeting` model, and *then* changed the primary keys to a UUIDField?

Comment: Yeah Yeah. That's what I did.

Comment: @TheMir: if there are no meetings yet, it might be better to remove the `Meeting` model, make migrations, and then add a new one, such that the `ForeignKey`s link to the correct field.

Comment: Yes.  It did work. I just removed the Meeting model then did migrations. finally Added the Meeting model and migrated again. Would you like to add a new answer to approve it?

Answer (score 0):

First save Student objects and Teacher objects

```
>> student_data = {'firstname': 'John', 'last_name', 'Doe', }
>> student1 = Student.objects.create(**student_data )
>>student_data = {'firstname': 'Test', 'last_name', 'Test', }
>> student2 = Student.objects.create(**student_data )

>> teacher_data  = {'firstname': 'TeacherJohn', 'last_name': 'TeacherDoe', 'email': 'john.doe@mail.com'}
>> teacher = Teacher.objects.create(**teacher_data )
```

Then create a Meeting object with the other fields( other than m2m). Then add/set the m2m objects.

```
meeting = Meeting.objects.create(**the_model_fields_as_dict)
meeting.student.add(student1, student2)
meeting.teacher.add(teacher )
```